# How to access the blob storage in Microsoft Azure HDInsight?

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I have just created a Spark based HDInsight cluster. I have selected a blob storage that I created before, while creating the cluster. However, I have no idea how to access that blob storage from within the VM created there. I have read many different tutorials, but couldn't get a proper answer.

I can see that the default container's folders/files correspond to the HDFS directories in the VM. Is it possible to add the blob storage to the default container, so that I can also access it just like an HDFS directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access blobs using **Azure PowerShell** **or Azure CLI** with cmdlets.

Refer : [Access blobs in Azure HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#access-blobs).

If you want to access blobs using **Azure Storage Explorer** with GUI:

Refer: [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

Comment: How can I add the blob storage to the default container? I can see that the  HDFS is corresponding directly to the default container. If I can add my blob storage in there, I could access the blob storage as HDFS, right?

Comment: @pythonic
During the HDInsight cluster creation process, you can specify a blob container in Azure Storage as the default file system. You cannot add any additional blob storage account as HDFS.
For more details, go through "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage".

Comment: You can add additional storage to Hadoop. For example, you can combine s3, hdfs, and wasb